# Concat multiple fields into one string, then group by it using collection to find sum of each group

Tags: java, collections, sum

Imagine I have the following fields:

```
>  String name1
>  String name2
>  String name3
>  BigDecimal amount
```

I want to group them by using one `String` which is the concatenation of name1, name2 and name3.

For example:

```
name1 = hi
name2 = am
name3 = sarah

String newString = hiamsarah
```

Then, after I manage to group the objects by the chained `String`, I want to get the overall sum of the `amount` field for each group.

Is this possible?

I've tried any possible way, but I just can't get through it. Also, I'm kind of new to collections.

Comment: Can you please show what you already have? Also please explain what do you mean by "Amount of each group"? What exactly is the group? You also mentioned collections, but I don't see any in you example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your instances are contained within a `List` and that within your class there is a method to return the chained names, you could use the collection stream and group by your instances with the terminal operation `collect(Collectors.toMap())`.

The chained value can be used as the key, the `BigDecimal` value as the value corresponding to the key and finally the collision cases can be handled by summing the `BigDecimal` values.

Since you didn't provide the code of the class you're referring to, I declared a class named `MyClass` containing the 3 `String` fields and the `BigDecimal`. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new MyClass("I", "am", "Sarah", BigDecimal.valueOf(5.33)),
                new MyClass("I", "am", "Frank", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.75)),
                new MyClass("I", "am", "Sarah", BigDecimal.valueOf(3.56)),
                new MyClass("I", "am", "Frank", BigDecimal.valueOf(7.12)),
                new MyClass("I", "am", "John", BigDecimal.valueOf(1.11))
        ));

        Map<String, BigDecimal> mapRes = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(mc -> mc.chainNames(), mc -> mc.getAmount(), (decimal1, decimal2) -> decimal1.add(decimal2)));

        System.out.println(mapRes);
    }
}
```

Test class implementation (`MyClass`):

```
class MyClass {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    private String name3;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public MyClass(String name1, String name2, String name3, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.name2 = name2;
        this.name3 = name3;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /* ... your implementation ...*/

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String chainNames() {
        StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder(name1);
        strBld.append(name2);
        strBld.append(name3);
        return strBld.toString();
    }
}
```

Here there is also a link to test the code:

https://ideone.com/IL1ZQ8

Answer (score 1):

1. To concatenate multiple strings, there is method [`String::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)), the first argument is a delimiter which can be an empty string `String.join("", name1, name2, name3)`
2. To group by some values in a list and summarize a certain value, Stream API should be used with `Collectors.groupingBy` + [`Collectors.reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

Assuming that the given class is implemented as a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) provided since Java 14, the following implementation is offered:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    record MyObj(String name1, String name2, String name3, BigDecimal amount) {
        public String fullName() {
            return String.join("", name1, name2, name3);
        }
    };
    
    List<MyObj> list = List.of(
            new MyObj("I", "am", "Sarah", BigDecimal.valueOf(5.33)),
            new MyObj("I", "am", "Frank", BigDecimal.valueOf(2.75)),
            new MyObj("I", "am", "Sarah", BigDecimal.valueOf(3.56)),
            new MyObj("I", "am", "Frank", BigDecimal.valueOf(7.12)),
            new MyObj("I", "am", "John",  BigDecimal.valueOf(1.11))
    );

    Map<String, BigDecimal> mapRes = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                MyObj::fullName, 
                Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, MyObj::amount, BigDecimal::add)
            ));

    System.out.println(mapRes);
}
```

Output:

```java
{IamJohn=1.11, IamSarah=8.89, IamFrank=9.87}
```